# How to use Autocreated DataSet - TableAdapterManager

Tags: c#, dataset, tableadapter

(Sorry for my bad English)

I have imported an access database to a C# winform project (.net 4.0) in visual studio 2013. It automatically creates a .cs file with a DataSet, TableAdapter and a TableAdapterManager.
I import data from the database to the DataSet, without error. I succeed to manipulate data, and save change to the database with TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll().

But now I try to insert new data, with relation between tables.
For example, a database like mine

Parent table :
autonum key
string parentname

Child table
autonum key
string childname
int parentKey

First try :
I create a new record with parentTable.AddparenttableRow(data ...) and get a parentRow.
I create a new record with childTable.AddchildtableRow(parentRow, data ...)

But if I call TableAdpaterManager.UpdateAll(), I get an error "can't add or modify a record because a related record is required in parentTable" (not the real message, it's a translation). I think that AddchildtableRow create the correct relation. And another problem appears : because of the error, the database isn't modified (which is good), but the records I had add, are always in the table of the DataSet.

So I try another method : TableAdpaterManager.tablenameTableAdpater.Insert()
First I insert a parentRow without any problem. But when I want to insert a childRow, the insert function asks for the parent key. But I don't have it (the insert parent call doesn't return the key).

My question is : how can I use the DataSet, TableAdapter and TableAdapterManager to insert records in the DataSet AND in the database, and with a transaction (if there is an error, the data won't be written to the database, and won't be added to the DataSet) ? And actually, how to correctly use these classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the typed dataset code. Switch between the default `TableAdapterManager.UpdateOrderOption.InsertUpdateDelete` to `UpdateInsertDelete` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384509.aspx)). For hierarchical updates you have to merge new values for your identity columns ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks9f57t0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379699/dataset-autoincrement-issue). The way ADO.NET deals with preventing collisions with it's disconnected dataset, it assigns negative IDENTITY column values, because it wouldn't know a possible positive number that IS NOT a collision as it's disconnected. Also [managing a @@identity crisis with parent-child relations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971502.aspx). The typed dataset technology also had issues with circular table references.

Comment: Sorry, I saw your answer, and forgot to respond ! Thank for your help, it was a good beginning for me.